# bad operand "-" for android.widget.EditText, "int"

Tags: android

i am required to do an app of calculating solar cell temperature and here below is my code

i can't figure to how to correct the error .
[the formula of calculating the cell temperature](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RScqD.png)

```
import android.os.PersistableBundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String TAG = "Mymessage";

//variable (ambient temperature ,normal operating cell temperature ,insolation level .
EditText input1;
EditText input2;
EditText input3;
TextView result;
Button Calculate;

float num1,num2,num3,sum;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");


    //locate the input
    input1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input1Ambient);
    input2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input2NOCT);
    input3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input3insolation);
    result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result);
    Calculate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_calculation);

}




@Override
protected void onStart (){
    super.onStart();

    //Performing Calculation
        Calculate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                num1=Float.parseFloat(input1.getText().toString());
                num2=Float.parseFloat(input2.getText().toString());
                num3=Float.parseFloat(input3.getText().toString());
                sum=input1+((input2 - 20/ 80))*input3 ;
                Calculate.setText(Float.toString(sum));
            }
        });
    Log.i(TAG,"onStart");
}
```

The line below is my XML file ,basically is just 3 EditText which is for the input ,1 TextView for the answer and 1 button for doing the calculation .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.asus.fyp.MainActivity">


<Button
    android:id="@+id/bt_calculation"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="177dp"
    android:text="@string/calculation"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.501"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/input1Ambient"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/ambient_temperature_c"
    android:inputType="numberSigned"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/input2NOCT"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="84dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/NOCT"
    android:inputType="numberSigned"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/input1Ambient" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/input3insolation"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/insolation"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/input2NOCT" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/result"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="Result"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bt_calculation"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/input3insolation" />
```

Comment: `input1` `input2` and `input3` are references of `EditText`. Use `num1` ,`num2` and `num3` instead .

Comment: but the error code is on this line                 ' sum=input1+((input2 - 20/ 80))*input3 ; '

Answer (score 0):

You have parsed the input1,input2 => edit texts into Floats... and then in your formula line

```
sum=input1+((input2 - 20/ 80))*input3 ; ---- erronous
```

you have used input1,input2 (edittexts) rather than float values (num1,num2). 
Actually by doing this you are saving value of an edit text in a float variable. 
change it to

```
sum=num1+(num2 - (20/ 80))*num3 ;--- correct
```

have also corrected the brackets... 
its working fine now. :)

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are using the following:

```
sum=input1+((input2 - 20/ 80))*input3 ;
```

where input1, input2, and input3 is a EditText:

```
EditText input1;
EditText input2;
EditText input3;
```

The correct one is using the following:

```
num1 = Float.parseFloat(input1.getText().toString());
num2 = Float.parseFloat(input2.getText().toString()); 
num3 = Float.parseFloat(input3.getText().toString());
sum= num1 + ((num2 - 20/ 80)) * num3;
```

Your logic error shouldn't be happened if you're using a standard naming convention in your code. For example, you should always use a variable name which is directly telling what View you are using.

**First**, this is not correct and didn't give you any information about the variable:

```
EditText input1;
```

instead, use a more descriptive name like this:

```
EditText edtInput;
```

or this:

```
EditText edtAmbient;
```

**Second**, you shouldn't use a variable name starting with capital case like this:

```
Button Calculate;
```

Instead, use this:

```
Button btnCalculate;
```

You can follow the following guideline for Android:

https://github.com/joielechong/android-guidelines/blob/master/project_and_code_guidelines.md

or

https://github.com/ribot/android-guidelines/blob/master/project_and_code_guidelines.md